# this error is show in cli to connect iot core

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

aws iot describe-endpoint

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeEndpoint operation: User: arn:aws:iam::548217278864:user/name is not authorized to perform: iot:DescribeEndpoint because no identity-based policy allows the iot:DescribeEndpoint action

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This the common problem most new-comers will face. First create your Policy and attach it to your Certificate. If still also same error continues, then it means you have not assigned it the User. For this go to IAM and create the your Policy (usually go with same name as in iot-core) and select that Policy and assign it to the respective User.